# Creating dataframe using dictionary of series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

What do you mean by dictionary of series and how to create a dataframe using dictionary of series??

And also is below code represent creating dataframe using dictionary of series:

**pd.DataFrame({0:{'name':'ABC','age':10}, 1:{'name': 'XYZ','AGE':20}})**

And can we create a series like below code??

**pd.Series ({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[1,2,3,4,5]})**

I was teaching my sister and I told her we can't create series like above code!! Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Series is **one-dimensional array which has labels**, in which the labels are referred to as the index. A Series must be of one datatype. In your example above of a series, you would have two indices, A & B, which correspond to the lists [1,2,3,4,5] and [1,2,3,4,5] respectively. Your series would look like:

```
A [1,2,3,4,5]
B [1,2,3,4,5]
```

A DataFrame is a **two-dimensional data structure with columns of different names and potentially different types**. In your example above, 0 & 1, would be the column names while name, age, and AGE would be the indices since age != AGE. Your data frame would look like:

```
     0    1
AGE  NaN  20 
age  10   NaN
name ABC  XYZ
```

Since DataFrames are two-dimensional and can support multiple datatypes, you can construct a DataFrame from multiple Series. For example:

```
pd.DataFrame({0:pd.Series(['ABC',10],index=['name','age']), 1:pd.Series(['XYZ',20],index = ['name','AGE'])})
```

Which would give you the same result. Hope this helps! For more reading/info: [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html)

Comment: The last example you have given, is that a dataframe created using dictionary of series??

Comment: Yes, it is a data frame created from multiple series.